# Como actualizar componente - Angular

Tags: angular

alguien me puede ayudar estoy realizando una tabla dinámica atravez de JSON.
Tengo en mi archivo un component util.ts que tiene las configuraciones iniciales que va tener la tabla pero luego se va cambiar en base al resultado de la base de datos.
cuando inicia si se visualiza segun la tabla que configuramos, pero al momento de llamar a la base de datos que arroja en json los headers no se actualiza.

En mi **HTML.COMPONENT**  Tengo un componente que estaba stg-table 2

```
 <stg-table2 [options]="options" [dataSource]="dataSources" [headers]="headers" [optionsObserver]="optObs" >
            </stg-table2>
```

**En mi component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {   
        let profile = this.user.get('profile'); 
        this.options=tableOptions;
        this.tableConf = tableConf; 
        this.headers=tableHeaders; 
        this.getServerData(profile.cod_bt);
        
    } 

private getServerData(codBT?: string): void {
         
        this.loading = true; 
        this.tableConf = tableConf; 
        
        this.ant.getColaboradoresdData(codBT).subscribe(x => { 
            this.dataSources=[]; 
            this.headers=[]
            
            //this.optObs.next({ body: { loading: { enabled: true } } });
            let r = x.body.resultado;
            this.headers =  eval(r.his.JSONNHEAD1) ;
            this.dataSources =r.bloq   
            this.headers=eval('[{key:"des_sec",label:"Asesor"}]')
            console.log(eval(r.his.JSONNHEAD1))
            console.log(this.dataSources)
             
            this.loadingObs = false;  
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
            
        }); 
        console.log(this.optObs)
        
    }
```

**Util.ts**

```
export const loadingConf = {
    height: '307px'
};
export const tableHeaders=[
    {
        key:'des_sec',
        label:'Asesor',
        style:{
            'max-width':'null',
            'width':'null'
        }
    },
    {
        label:'Variables para la activación de monetización',
        subs:[
            {
                key:'cob_sal',
                label:'Saldo de Cartera',
                format:{
                    type:'percent'
                } 
            },
            {
                key:'cob_cli',
                label:'Stock de Clientes',
                format:{
                    type:'percent'
                } 
            },
            {
                key:'cob_efec1',
                label:'Efectividad -30 a 0 días',
                format:{
                    type:'percent'
                } 
            },
            {
                key:'cob_efec2',
                label:'Efectividad 1 a 30 días',
                format:{
                    type:'percent'
                } 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label:'Monetizacion',
        subs:[
            {
                key:'bob',
                label:'Bono Base',
                format:{
                    type:'decimal'
                }
            },
            {
                key:'bop',
                label:' Bono Plus',
                format:{
                    type:'decimal'
                }
            },
            {
                key:'bos',
                label:'Bono Super Plus',
                format:{
                    type:'decimal'
                }
            },
            {
                key:'bot',
                label:'Total Monetizado', 
                format:{
                    type:'decimal'
                }
            },
            {
                key:'smf',
                label:'Semaforo', 
                format:{
                    type:'icon',
                    params:{
                        size:'18px'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
export const tableOptions={
    style:{
        'font-size':'12px'
    },
    header:{
        style:{
            'background':'rgb(79, 129, 189)'
        },
        cellStyle:{
            'height':'40px',
            'width':'85px',
            'min-width':'85px',
            'max-width':'85px'
        }
    }
};
export const tableConf = {
    table: {
        height: '400px',
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(31, 73, 125)'
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216)'
        grid: STG_GRID_STYLE
    },
    header: {
        'min-width': '100px',
        'background-color':'rgb(79,129,189)'
    }
};
 
export const tableConf2 = {
    table: {
        height: '400px',
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(31, 73, 125)'
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216)'
        grid: STG_GRID_STYLE
    },
    header: {
        'min-width': '100px',
        'background-color':'rgb(79,129,189)'
    }
};
export const tableConf3 = {
    table: {
        height: '400px',
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(31, 73, 125)'
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216)'
        grid: STG_GRID_STYLE
    },
    header: {
        'min-width': '100px',
        'background-color':'rgb(79,129,189)'
    }
};
export const tableConf4 = {
    table: {
        height: '400px',
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(31, 73, 125)'
        //grid: '1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216)'
        grid: STG_GRID_STYLE
    },
    header: {
        'min-width': '100px',
        'background-color':'rgb(79,129,189)'
    }
};
```

**Headers que viene desde BD**

```
[
    {
        "label": "DOR",
        "key": "HDOR"
    },
    {
        "label": "Agentes Corresponsales",
        "key": "RNUMCORRES"
    },
    {
        "label": "Agentes Satelitales",
        "key": "RNUMCOSATE"
    },
    {
        "label": "Cosechas 3 y 6 meses",
        "key": "RNUMCOSE3A6"
    }
]
```

**Data que viene desde BD**

```
{
    "Fecha": "2022-10-31",
    "HCOLBT": "TJFLM100",
    "HCOLTIP": "8",
    "HDOR": 50,
    "RNUMCORRES": 20,
    "RNUMCOSATE": 40,
    "RNUMCOSE3A6": 180
}
```

Comment: Quieres que se inicialice con unos datos preestablecidos y luego se actualice con datos que vienen desde la BD? Intentaste implementar el `AfterViewInit` o tal vez `AfterViewChecked`?

Comment: @René en el constructor? No amigo se poco angular no se cómo usar esos funciones

Comment: El constructor en Angular es solamente `constructor() {}`, en el código que mandaste estas usando el ciclo de vida de Angular con ese `ngOnInit`, lo que hace que al inicializar el componente se carguen los datos, lo cual en teoría sirve para inicializar la tabla con los datos por defecto (también lo puedes meter en el constructor), checa [Angular: Componentes y sus ciclos de vida](https://medium.com/angular-chile/angular-componentes-y-sus-ciclos-de-vida-aa639e13a688), ya solamente tendrías que meter la función que trae los datos de la BD en el ciclo de que necesites.

Comment: Por otra parte agrega un `try-catch` o un `catchError` en el servicio por si no te traen nada los datos, así sabes más fácil donde está el error. [Documentación catchError](https://puntotech.github.io/rxjs-docu/operators/error-handling/catchError)

Comment: @René entonces en uno de ellos puedo llamar. La función this.getServerData(profile.cod_bt)

Comment: Si, ya dependerá de cuál necesites ya que actúan de diferente forma. Una forma fácil de ver eso es agregar un `console.log` dentro de las que uses para que entiendas de forma más fácil como se van ejecutando.

Comment: @René si ya he visto la documentación y me parece muy interesante el ciclo de vida del componente, tengo una consulta hay un evento botón que llama a la función this.getserverdata(profile.codbt) esa función como se puede colocar en el afterviewinit?

Comment: Quieres que el botón se muestre / oculte antes/después de que carguen los datos de la BD? Podrías usar un booleano, y cambias el valor dentro del ciclo de vida, en el HTML solamente agregas `*ngIf` y con eso bastaría.

Comment: @René hice pero nada no se actualiza el componente de html

Comment: Por que utilizas eval?

Comment: Para formatearlo en JSon ya que de la base de datos viene con comillas al comienzo

Comment: Faltaría ver algo más de código para ver donde esta el error, como ver donde los muestras y que dice exactamente el error.